# Script to transfer data from invoice sheet to database

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

This is my first post and I'm new to scripts. Upon searching through multiple questions similar to mine, I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

**I want to create a macro that pulls specific data from my Invoice sheet and add it to the next available line on the Data sheet. After the data has been added to the Data sheet, I want it to reset the Invoice sheet and clear those fields while also adding 1 to the job # (currently at 100, moves to 101 after macro has completed the move, then 102 and so on).**

I created a simplified dummy sheet for reference:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o-1BOw7H8-_BIQYynEempd06XM0ozC0Kln5qWW0gruM/edit?usp=sharing

I made a helper line on row 18 of the information to be transferred, but I don't know if that's necessary for the process or not.

Comment: Welcome. While including a link to a spreadsheet could be helpful, questions should be self-contained. In other words, please add enough details to the question itself including a simplified version of you code (minimal, complete and verifiable example)

Comment: I actually figured it out and I'm set to go! Thank you for letting me know though!

Comment: Great. Please consider to share your solution. Ref. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer